# Extract correct format of key and cert files from .p12 file for a SSL MEAN App?

Tags: mac-osx, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm writing a MEAN app for my university department on my Mac development machine. I started with the boilerplate from mean.io. In the configuration file `config/env/all.js`, there is a section for configuring SSL:

```
https: {
    port: false,

    // Paths to key and cert as string
    ssl: {
      key: '',
      cert: ''
    }
}
```

I understand that I'm supposed to change `port:false` to the port I'm using for SSL, `port:443`, and to provide the filepaths to the key and cert.

The steps I've taken:

- create directory `ssl` in the app root
- open Keychain Access on mac
- under `Certificates` on the left, I right click on my department's CA-issued (DigiCert) Certificate and click on `Export`
- Save as `Certificates.p12` in `app_root/ssl`
- Click OK when prompted to enter a password to protect exported file to skip doing so

Here's where I'm confused. Based on instructions found [here](https://github.com/linnovate/mean#environmental-settings) the paths are to the public key and certificate. How do I extract the public key from this `Certificates.p12` file, and how do I extract the `certificate` from it such that the mean app will correctly load it?

Additional steps I've taken, attempting instructions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497719/how-to-extract-a-public-private-key-from-a-pkcs12-file-with-openssl-for-later-us):

#### public key generation

- `cd ssl`
- `openssl pkcs12 -in Certificates.p12 -nocerts -nodes | openssl rsa > id_rsa`
- `openssl rsa -in id_rsa -pubout > pubkey.txt`

#### certificate generation

- `openssl pkcs12 -in Certificates.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out pubcert.txt`

Then I set the following:

```
https: {
    port: 443,

    // Paths to key and cert as string
    ssl: {
      key: rootPath + '/ssl/pubkey.txt',
      cert: rootPath + '/ssl/pubcert.txt'
    }
}
```

On trying to run the server, I get the following error:

```
crypto.js:100
      c.context.setKey(options.key);
            ^
Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
    at Object.exports.createCredentials (crypto.js:100:17)
    at Server (tls.js:1127:28)
    at new Server (https.js:35:14)
    at Object.exports.createServer (https.js:54:10)
```

Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

After following [this short tutorial](http://gaboesquivel.com/blog/2014/nodejs-https-and-ssl-certificate-for-development/) I attempted using my server's **private** key, not the public key.

#### private key generation from Certificates.p12:

`openssl pkcs12 -in Certificates.p12 -nocerts -nodes > key.pem`

#### public cert generation from Certificates.p12:

`openssl pkcs12 -in Certificates.p12 -clcerts -nokeys > cert.pem`

I then set `key: rootPath + '/ssl/key.pem'` and `cert: rootPath + '/ssl/cert.pem'`

And the server successfully started. I connected through a browser to my department's domain name with https and using the https port I assigned. It connected successfully and gave a green lock icon. It downloaded the html from the app index.html, but it won't render anything -- it just sits there loading. The server console logged a successful GET request with 200 OK code response.